# Optimizing if conditional statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, optimization, conditional-statements

Is there a better way to write the below?

```
if ((A && B) || (A && B && C)) { ... }
```

which means I cannot do

```
if ((A && B) || C) { ... }
```

Comment: Simplify to `if (A & B) {`. You may well have wanted to use && instead, also. `if (A && B) {` C is irrelevant

Comment: are you sure you want to use bitwise AND?

Comment: My bad. Supposed to be AND not bitwise operation. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logical rules to simplify the statement:

```
(A && B) || (A && B && C)
```

Factorizing the common part (`A && B`) you get:

```
(A && B) && (true || C)
```

And of course `true || C` is always true so that entire group becomes a "don't care" and can be discarded. That leaves just:

```
A && B
```

There are other ways to arrive at the same result. In this case, even writing out a basic truth table would have made it pretty obvious.

For more complicated expressions, the use of a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) can be helpful.